# RxJava Room with Flowable: Returning new rows only

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

We decided to use Flowable of RxJava with Room persistence library. We have tables in which content is added by services on indefinite intervals(there are 2-3 update inserts every few seconds) and that table's rows are subscribed in BaseAdapter for making changes in view on live basis.

The problem is that when ever there is any update/insert operation, we get whole list again making the base adaptor regenerate the view. There can be delete operations as well making the length of rows no use to us.

I want to ask if there is any other operator which supports live data and call onNext on new data, and provide whole list on delete operations.

Answer (score 1):

> are subscribed in **BaseAdapter**

Use RecyclerView with fine-grained notify* calls like `notifyItemInserted` instead of a ListView

> The problem is that when ever there is any update/insert operation, we get whole list again

That is completely expected behavior with both `LiveData<List<T>>` and `Flowable<List<T>>`.

> making the base adaptor regenerate the view.

That's because you aren't using `DiffUtil` or you aren't using RecyclerView's new addition, `ListAdapter` (which handles the diffing internally and automatically)

> provide whole list on delete operations.

It actually already provides the whole list (without the deleted items, of course).

---

The solution from AAC side is to use `DataSource.Factory<Integer, T>` instead of `Flowable<List<T>>/LiveData<List<T>>` so that you can create a `LiveData<PagedList<T>>` via a `LivePagedListBuilder` which you can set to your `PagedListAdapter`. That way, it only fetches a given page size instead of the whole list, and handles diffing.

**EDIT:**

```
@Entity(tableName = Task.TABLE_NAME)
public class Task {
    public static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Task oldItem, @NonNull Task newItem) {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Task oldItem, @NonNull Task newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }
    };

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TASK";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "task_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TEXT = "task_text";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "task_date";
```

and

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Task.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + Task.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC ")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, Task> tasksSortedByDate();

    // ...
}
```

and

```
public class TaskViewModel
        extends ViewModel {
    private final TaskDao taskDao;

    private LiveData<PagedList<Task>> liveResults;

    public TaskViewModel(TaskDao taskDao) {
        this.taskDao = taskDao;
        liveResults = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(taskDao.tasksSortedByDate(),
                                                 new PagedList.Config.Builder() //
                                                         .setPageSize(20) //
                                                         .setPrefetchDistance(20) //
                                                         .setEnablePlaceholders(true) //
                                                         .build())
                .setInitialLoadKey(0)
                .build();
    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<Task>> getTasks() {
        return liveResults;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TaskFragment
        extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        TaskViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TaskViewModel.class);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        final TaskAdapter taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
        viewModel.getTasks().observe(this, pagedList -> {
            //noinspection Convert2MethodRef
            taskAdapter.submitList(pagedList);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        viewModel.getTasks().removeObservers(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TaskAdapter
        extends PagedListAdapter<Task, TaskAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public TaskAdapter() {
        super(Task.DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for kind answer, Can you, please, add more details to the last part?

Comment: "ListAdapter (which handles the diffing internally and automatically)" - does that imply that entities must override `equals`?

Comment: @TKK well not if you implement the `areContentsTheSame` differently than in this answer

Answer (score 0):

No, With room, there aren't. If you are using Rx with Room, you can use [Diff util](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil)
or you can use [List Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter)
There's also a variation called SortedListAdapter

Providing a sample implementation from developer android

```
@Dao
 interface UserDao {
     @Query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY lastName ASC")
     public abstract LiveData<List<User>> usersByLastName();
 }

 class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
     public final LiveData<List<User>> usersList;
     public MyViewModel(UserDao userDao) {
         usersList = userDao.usersByLastName();
     }
 }

 class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
         super.onCreate(savedState);
         MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
         RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.user_list);
         UserAdapter<User> adapter = new UserAdapter();
         viewModel.usersList.observe(this, list -> adapter.submitList(list));
         recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
 }

 class UserAdapter extends ListAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> {
     public UserAdapter() {
         super(User.DIFF_CALLBACK);
     }
     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.bindTo(getItem(position));
     }
     public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User> DIFF_CALLBACK =
             new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {
         @Override
         public boolean areItemsTheSame(
                 @NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
             // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
             return oldUser.getId() == newUser.getId();
         }
         @Override
         public boolean areContentsTheSame(
                 @NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
             // NOTE: if you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals()
             // Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.
             return oldUser.equals(newUser);
         }
     }
 }
```

Or, you can create a RXBus implementation, and when you are inserting data into database, publish an event with the added/deleted data. Subscribe to it, and you can get what you want.